# How to map types with conditional properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to tranform an object to another object with proper type safety. My code outlines how I'm intending to use the mapped object, but I have typescript errors. I could of course just use `@ts-ignore`, but I'm trying to find a proper way of how to do this.

```
type RoutesConfig = Record<string | number | symbol, RouteConfig>

type RouteConfig = {
    path: string
    children?: RoutesConfig
}

// /flattens/ the defined routes by extracting the child routes, omitting the path and children properties
type Routes<T extends RoutesConfig> = {
    [Property in keyof T]: Routes<T[Property]['children']>
}

const routes = defineRoutes({
  user: {
    path: 'user',
    children: {
        profile: {
            path: 'profile'
        },
        posts: {
            path: 'posts',
            children: {
                postId: {
                    path: ':postId',
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
})

// maps an object to Routes type
function defineRoutes<T extends RoutesConfig>(routes: T): T {
    return routes
}

const mappedRoutes = generateRoutes(routes)

// actually transforms the object
function generateRoutes<T extends RoutesConfig>(routes: T, obj: Routes<T> = {}): Routes<T> {
    Object.keys(routes).forEach((key: keyof T) => {
        const route = routes[key]
        obj[key] = route.children
            ? generateRoutes(route.children, obj[key])
            : {}
    })
    return obj
}

console.log(mappedRoutes)
console.log(mappedRoutes.user.profile)
console.log(mappedRoutes.user.posts.postId)
```

[Typescript REPL URL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAJQPYFcwwM4GEkDsBmAlgOZwC8iMAxkgE4AmAPBmLYbqQD5y4oC2AIxi043DBEFIANgBpEqdDgIkAfKFCRY8tDCVFSFAN6g4puFACGYABYAuOCzYcTZqtcJT6tGLgD895B1sPH1QAF91EAB6KLgo-CkrdFwMWJt4ehgiXBh6OFoFTDgBCDgYAA9WCyowdlJ0uDcPPIKguSQ+QjBajjgGyxs4C1w8ps9vXHMC2FpazA1oeED0DEYAFTLKn3oMbRW9VXI4YxAzOABtAAVp4Ug4djgAaxgIJHw4NYBdAMLVtaubrMIJ9zgByMZeHygz5qEARECgGgpMD5X5HTLZGDLTAAChOphQGGE9nxZgGdjgoMJwlBMhcpghExJ9LOUzeHhgzNOrJ55PsoKgBSIUhgoJZZzCdO5vKQLAwXJ5vKsFIFsrAGFp4sVjJ8CsV+qgaoAkvQ9frzeZlfzbIaWCbNdKLWZ4U64C7Fe7TO74WEAJSRGJwPgWKC7YZwJACABW1BRYCQeyKmhgoHwKFwNUIeDgGPYWN+602yR2ieCymIKhxrRW9jWvtrxxZ3jAKFok2r8zhkSRLCDIdg9GxuwoxB8wis+aCVd+-oR0Vi1RbFikUlKVRS+DofF2DUjMZqqfTmezo5ytAnQ8LFWLuyHBwr06Ctfa0Z+QXWKiOhj9b5WH8bjoAPLRrGAB0zwQBgj4rL6oGbrQACi1TWDiOIQfYEFvB8vrkJ+pI8j2KIdkcHYYOcEGfFqph7uRLyfCRhSgTquBUayvhwKe47oEO0EwEx7jjD4L5RrRwKzq6JKem64lmM2raTHu4TdngGDSHxUhIMQOLBlAA5DrOPZqaBGlaTpem-KB1K0KBgrsiKBkqUZJnaf2uRDpZRLWba6o2ca9CzkAA)

There are specifically two errors:

1. `Routes<T[Property]['children']>` errors, as `T[Property]['children']` could be undefined. In this case, I want the recursion to end. I've tried setting the value to `Required`, or have T extend RoutesConfig and undefined. Conditional types also didn't work, or I might have just used the wrong. I think I have to use `infer` in my mapped type, but don't know where...
2. I cannot assign `{}` to `obj`, as it requires the value to be of type `Routes<T>`. Do properties of `Routes<T>` have to be optional, to allow initial assignment?  `obj: any = {}` also works, but seems hacky...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning #1, if you had written down the whole algorithm with the base case, I am sure you would have found the solution: `T` can be `RoutesConfig | undefined`; when it's `undefined` it's the base case, return `Empty` (to match your implementation), otherwise map and recur.

```js
type Empty = { [k in PropertyKey]: never };

type Routes<T extends RoutesConfig | undefined> = T extends RoutesConfig
    ? { [P in keyof T]: Routes<T[P]['children']> }
    : Empty;
```

---

Concerning #2,  my answer is going to disappoint but I usually give up and try to extract the part that is easy to type and harder to implement from the part that is harder to type but obviously correct:

```js
type RoutesResult = { [k: PropertyKey]: Empty | RoutesResult };

const mapper = ([key, route]: [PropertyKey, RouteConfig]): [PropertyKey, RoutesResult] => 
    [key, route.children ? generateRoutes(route.children) : {}];
```

That's where we cheat: `generateRoutes` is really returning `RoutesResult` instead of `Routes<T>`, so we assert it.

```js
const generateRoutes = <T extends RoutesConfig>(routes: T): Routes<T> =>
    Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(routes).map(mapper)) as Routes<T>;
```

Note however that there is nothing really going on in this function any more: it's just the logic for mapping an object, so it is less dangerous to use `as`.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0&ts=4.9.4#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2BAzgYTgOwGYEsDmUAvLBAMZwBOAJgDwAKlckloA0hCADSyLIY4CAPgBQoSLySoYqBABtgxKAG8oAbQDWALiiNmEViA4gAujoCiAWzCgoAH0nIUMlPMUBfMeGhWbIJaqaULiYukws7JxmUJgQAG4GUJ5eEvBSAniEJMoiUHlQYACGwAAWOijAlCH4uflkJbhy1JQQmAD8OmlOGQQiyQD0-VD92HLFyJgoQ6XQ1BB4sdRQTFIoUABG-hAAHpWFZMDVUDNQ9Y1LK048cJa4wIeYhCdFpVCFmEtnTS2hYOEGh1QKWgXVQtAAKkIlOCoDsJtQ1qD0FhMrU8m0VOp6MFQhpOHBsFBwdEkRC1PQTGoAORfZqtKkmKGefJQCzWUAiEQUSaKS6oJRzBYQJEAChyeQQKAMOnF+ReZSgVMlBipXDRpwa31aMvVLL+BMaEB1LJNcuKCqp+rwcggVN1+XcatNeTAcAqKGNzr15p0lrdwBQqvtptpP09XtNroqAElqOGI175b6tFHgLGgwnTczM9ms+rs553ABKTmDKCWQpgNbvKBwdYAK3IimAcEc-PEEBE2AQmAOuCwUEFIWFfDBMLhrQRbeRgnwQhFfI9RKLOhhsryLWACEooUXfVLQ32W8Kcjk-j2k2wVEsaxOdcbB053Iq5crLCUIs0nB4fOi5P+hjGDwoI9PgJgrliAGRNw04uG4JjEFC6pfjBfIAHShq0UAYvgrQGMUI6rAuo4YZqdKYEWrIqO4JgANxPlgL64bElAEUiSgQrCuyToio4zpk86LquEGkpCiHqgA8g2TZodgTCWOYmCVLgqAilJD7AGhrTKapi5FmhFZgCKhksEWlGFLxqwQqIXKMYoJkQNQ7EkMx+HIKKen0bZkxwDaaFyHA+DGW+jlIiWz6+RA-mBcFYCQE5fFocqlBoVahrhYxkXRUFDkJasSVSilqYoKl-qxkWQA)