# Defining the right type for recursive call

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, nested

I have defined a function that recursively traverses a nested object (or not nested) and looks for a specific key, extracting its value

```
const findName = <T extends object>(obj: T, keyToFind: string): T[] => {
   return Object.entries(obj)
      .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
         if(key === keyToFind) {
            return acc.concat(value)
         } else {
            //is the next level of nesting an object so we can keep recursively searching for the key?
            if (typeof value === 'object') {
               return acc.concat(findName(value, keyToFind)) //problem is here because value is of type any
            } else {
               return acc
            }
         }
      }, [])
}
```

I'm trying to define a type for `value` as right now when I call `findName` in the recursive step I get the following error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.
      The types returned by 'slice(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
          Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.
```

I'm unsure on how to define a type so the compiler stops complaining about this.

This is the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGJQMIgLYAcA2BTAHjAvDAN4CwAUDJTAEQCOArlgE4CWWE1AXDANrlUDi-QSLqMmATy41oAQyj0IMAOoBBAMowASuxAYAblgAmMAEIBNGADYAzLICMABnv2AHABZXAIxtWA7EZ+rg6ezgCs1AA0wiIC1NBM9MAKTFjSpBSxWdQA7gAWzGncGVmlVNQAZmwYRukxZQ3UYLIoRTJQ8orU9Q2CAL7Rmb2iIGjM8iBM0rmyHIPDsdSj42C1xT0LgtT6shiM0zoQeoa1GwsDZ8PUaKlGLMDy7NJ8Q5siJW+Ny0wTU9zUXik80+ZSWYx+qzqrxBoJ2eza1FsDmcbk8Pn8gWC9lC9gilxhMD6+M2ROhmwAusSRKTejTYnTKJSyKTyKBILBQOhsHhCB9KGJmGwONwXlk+aUBZJprMICwAOZgLBYGCIAASqgAcgBxACiABEYAAVADyMGA9CYqTAUAAqhBmAAKACUMGNGpgACZHB6bAAdX30Rzeire-2B4PemCag1yBRKNSaPXgZVuz3ev0BoMekMesNZnOurQwGXyxXKtWa3UGixmi1W232pjOmBQEC1y1Ya12x1OqJU9qJZIWtri3q5AqpKEE6jADCyRRPEX93qjgnlWfz+3C3jLmGrtcSqpYGpTg+fJotBElhVK7pks-04EP0HfX7TYB5WRgOXGPv359xDcxj3I826igBwz7hBL7gm+-ytn+0FvGCKxrEI-5IY0FT0GAyQsOA751p2DbMIhmHnrITByvQrTWmBTLkcMDKMf0T4sQIUHsfyr6tn8NAEWxXFbK+kLrBhQnlHC+z-F6PoAPTegpHp3hJ9K7gBzGMQx5EXOJB6cRBlTVGhBmYRerTTLGXTqWuulCShPy8dMOSzGR7EOV+Jk2Q+2y7NJNBJoqKlcXZXHXLcIFQIuO56UhpksR5Tn-AJ3mGSJXmxfZUkIrJNhKUpwWqQImkhalILaZhJUHuSglnolkzSpCZWsc1HGtYsR4nmJjHmVeECyjeaTtdStUHvVfEzp+36-qNa7hcBDxRWBw2lPFPk8Q1-yAm5CXpaeqmVDheEEf85odl2jY7fZlHUbRUD0SttKPY+z3vK9EobRNCGzdBHmiehRU0NhuFQPhYCEedJFTD95HUDdNHEQ9mVnlVz6owSFW2c1NXNeN0wNTZ6NUKjzFMiyZBstAMBVKsGqXgQMAADyGjAuBRasSggF4ABWWDJAAfA6XPc9whqRDAADWWASIaIAAGIsKs3AJIrcpOqLPDkgQ-MA5QqQpGAro83zUAAHTEaw7BCzzTobKbtxJFgDoOrIwDAOLPBSxI4vZeSLr4DrnEsBUDpewQ+CEF7ssK6sLrxfrFqG67wCm2yi0OtltsYX0rMYPautlHJcksEoUAFHAbMwNghgYDAIAVBX0Cq8WhvCybMBHDAOTKg8htS1gaAwKkZ2yjXEgd1glEfs3FSTC25dewA-P2wcwA6UASGM9cwNl4eEAA5G3yT73H6kJ0wSdu6n4DpzTRh060Gd+Vg4tR-LitGE6We0rn+drXrWADbFjdv2dGJUBi8D9uQcmlM9BYFNhgEAcoHR3wfk7TkmBcDiyMseWoX8gA) with the current scenario

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I have managed to get that error sorted by setting reduce's generic to type `T[]` but `value` is still of type any so linting is kicking off, is there a way of defining it as being a string when we concatenate

```
const findName = <T extends object>(obj: T, keyToFind: string): T[] => {
   return Object.entries(obj)
      .reduce<T[]>((acc, [key, value]) => {
         if(key === keyToFind) {
            return acc.concat(value)
         } else {
            //is the next level of nesting an object so we can keep recursively searching for the key?
            if (typeof value === 'object') {
               return acc.concat(findName(value, keyToFind))
            } else {
               return acc
            }
         }
      }, [])
}
```

Comment: try use `Array<never>`.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have updated the question since using `T[]` worked for me, thank you for your recommendation, I'm looking to get value to be of type key on concatenation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `reduce`, you need to assert the type of the initializer if it is an empty datastructure, otherwise TS will not allow you to fill it, because the accumulator and the initializer need to be of the same type.

I let you figure out what type it should be, but try for starter to assert `[] as any[]` and the error will vanish.

Now if I can give an opinion/advice: don't use `concat` when you can use `push` in this context: you are pushing to a new array, the reduce expression is still pure and there is no observable side-effect inside it, but it's more efficient this way.

Comment: I have asserted the type the initializer should be as it is going to be always a string, so that part is fixed, since I have linting on and `value` is any, the linting is complaining, I wonder if there is a way to have a type that defines it. Thank you for your push suggestion!

Comment: You may want to look up this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75158246/how-to-map-types-with-conditional-properties/75160886#75160886

Comment: I don't think your function should return `T[]`. It's not the same type as the input, only wrapped in an array